# How to go back two viewControllers before, from ABPeoplepicker delegate method

Tags: objective-c, ios, delegates, modalviewcontroller

I'm developing an app which uses ABPeopleViewController, and i want to when the user finalized choosing a contact, go backward two viewcontroller before.
Here's how i am arriving to ABPeoplePickerNavigationController:
Tap in a button of a main view controller --> load modal (dialog) view controller --> tap in a button of the modal view controller --> load ABContacts.

I'm implementing the delegate of ABContacts in the modal view, which in turn has a delegate in the main view controller.

I want to go back from ABPeoplePicker delegate method to the main view controller.

Hope this understands and someone can help me, i didn't find anything like this.

My MainViewController.h:

```
@protocol ModalViewDialogDelegate

- (void)didReceiveMail:(NSString *)mail;

@end

@interface SetUpViewController : UIViewController<UITextFieldDelegate, ModalViewDialogDelegate>{
}
//...
```

My MainViewController.m:

```
  //...
  - (void)didReceiveMail:(NSString *)mail{

  [self.presentedViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
  //...
```

My ModalView.h:

```
#import <AddressBook/AddressBook.h>
#import <AddressBookUI/AddressBookUI.h>

@protocol ModalViewDialogDelegate;

@interface DialogViewController : UIViewController<ABNewPersonViewControllerDelegate, ABPeoplePickerNavigationControllerDelegate>{
   id<ModalViewDialogDelegate> delegate;
}

@property (nonatomic, assign) id<ModalViewDialogDelegate> delegate;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * mailSelected;
//...
```

My modalView.m:

```
 - (BOOL)peoplePickerNavigationController:(ABPeoplePickerNavigationController  *)peoplePicker shouldContinueAfterSelectingPerson:(ABRecordRef)person property:(ABPropertyID)property identifier:(ABMultiValueIdentifier)identifier{

    //...here i get the email person property and then i want to go backwards to the main view controller, not the modal.

    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

    //don't know if it's ok like this, because in the implementation also dismiss presented viewcontroller.
    [_delegate didReceiveMail:self.mailSelected];

    return NO;
}
return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try putting this

```
[_delegate didReceiveMail:self.mailSelected];
```

inside the completion block of the

```
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
```

that precedes it.

(If that doesnt work you can simply call the dissmiss twice on your maincontroller delegate method, each dismiss will remove one from the stack)

Comment: Thank you very much!! It works by calling the dismissModalViewController twice in the delegate method!

Answer (score 0):

```
[[[self presentingViewController]  presentingViewController] dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:nil];
```